# AWS Hadoop MapReduce - Word Count Average

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, word-count

Hi I have a csv data file as below.

bus,train,bus,TRAIN,car,bus,Train,CAr,car,Train,Cart,Bus,Bicycle,Bicycle,Car,Bus,Cart,Cart,Bicycle,Threewheel

I need to count the average word count in the above CSV using MapReduce.

Eg: Bus = 5/20 =0.25

I can get the word count easily but I need the Total Number of records (20 in this case) to take word count average. But Passing that to reduce function using global Variables did not work out. I tried to pass this as a key-value pair in the map. Key = "Total" Value = total Count to the reducer input. It was not successfull as well.

Any Suggestions to pass this Total Count from Map function to  Reducer Function?

I used One master and 3 slaves in EMR Cluster if that is a piece of needed information.

Thank You in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the pairs (K, V) where K is the word and V the times it appears, you can map all to a single key, lets say (W, (K, V)). Now you can reduce to obtain a total word count. Then you can make another map/reduce step to join the old keys with the new count.
Hope it helps.